# file_get_contents sporadically returns empty string when trying to read webpage

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to load a webpage with file_get_contents(), and am running into problems.

Basically, my web app will use the youtube data api to search for videos based on a user's query, and then read each video's youtube page to find information not provided by the api. I use file_get_contents() to read the youtube pages and then load the text into a DOM parser. Most of the time, this works like a charm. However, on occasion, I'll get warnings saying that  file_get_contents() returned an empty string (not for all videos, only for some of them). I know that the url I am providing is correct, because I echo a link to that url and it works as expected. I'll refresh the page, reopen my browser, switch to a different browser, etc. but nothing will work. Then, I'll leave the thing for an hour or two, come back to it, and it will magically work again!

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
function processNext($int) {
    // this function processes the next $int videos from the youtube data api response ($xmlDoc)
    global $xmlDoc;
    $begin = count($_SESSION["results"]) - $_SESSION["start"] + 1;
        /* $_SESSION["results"] is the array of already-processed videos
           $_SESSION["start"] and $_SESSION["end"] are the indexes of the first and last videos in the $xmlDoc
        */
    $end = count($_SESSION["results"]) - $_SESSION["start"] + $int;

    for ($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i++) {
        $video = $xmlDoc->entry[$i];
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        // this is the line that is causing me problems
        $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents(getWatchURL(getVidID($video->id)))); 

        $doc = $doc->documentElement;

               // then, do some processing on the $doc

    }
}
```

Is it possible that file_get_contents() is timing out? Is cURL a better tool for what I am doing?

**UPDATE:** I get the same results with cURL.

Comment: If it is a popular page, and many people are viewing it, it is possible that file_get_contents times out.  Check your php.ini and see what the default_socket_timeout is set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`$http_response_header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php). You can check the status code of the request. If it's anything other than `200`, something has likely gone wrong. [More about status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: Okay, I will definitely try this.

Comment: I did this, and I found that I was getting some 404 errors. BUT this was not the main source of my problem. The main problem appears to be that, sometimes, for some reason, file_get_contents() stops making new http requests. For example, when I call file_get_contents() 10 times, the first 5 requests will work, but after that, the http_response_header will remain exactly the same (including some cookie data which I know should be changing) for the next 5 requests, and the value returned will be an empty string. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: This wasn't the root of the problem, but at least now I can error check and repeat requests that fail. Also, I don't think I'm likely to get any more answers now... :)

Comment: I have the same problem so it would be great if someone figured this out. In my case I'm just doing something very simple: but getting the same results as above. My code: $somevar = file_get_contents("index.html");
echo "length=".strlen($somevar);

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, for about .5% of my calls to file_get_contents(), both response and $http_response_header are NULL. I temporarily fixed this by repeating the call up to 3 times if necessary, but that's not really a fix. This is happening on a Gentoo system, my Windows dev system has never shown this error.